# Simple method to configure network in CentOS 7

Tags: centos

In the CentOS 6, if I use the command `setup`, I can config the network in it, but in the CentOS 7, the `setup` GUI is different from the CentOS 6.

[image: screenshot]

I did not find the network configuration in the GUI. What is the new way to configure the network?

Comment: Different things are different. What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat, but not directly on this. I think the general direction has gone away from unified text-UI configuration tools. There *is* a TUI for network configuration, though: `sudo yum install NetworkManager-tui` and then run `nmtui`. I think that will give you what you're looking for.